# Add a combined legend that accounts for color, shape, and linetype, while keeping the original legends

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, data-visualization, legend

I have the following df:

```
df <- data.frame("id" = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B2", "B2", "B2"),
                 "group" = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                 "version" = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"),
                 "var_1" = 1:3,
                 "var_2" = 1:12)
```

I use the following code::

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = var_1, y = var_2, by = "id")) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "line", aes(color = factor(id), linetype = (version))) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "point", aes(color = factor(id), shape = (group))) +
  labs(color = "id", linetype = "version", shape = "group")
```

And get the following plot:

[image]

The problem is that in the 'id' legend, the shapes and linetypes are generic, and don't always match the correct shape/linetype.

**What I would like to do is make the legend for 'id' show the correct shape and linetype, *while preserving the separate, original legends for 'group' and 'version'*.**

This means that my goal is for the 'group' and 'version' legends to remain the same, but for the entries in the 'id' legend to have their shape and linetype modified as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through `guide_legend`.  Within that, you can override the default `aes()` specified via the other `ggplot2` commands to match what you want:

```
p + guides(color=guide_legend(
  override.aes = list(linetype=c(1,3,1,3), shape=c(16,16,17,17))))
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but is there a way to do it without manually specifying the linetype/shape?

Comment: Not exactly from my knowledge.  ggplot basically maintains a separate legend for each `aes()`.  So that means that when you have a legend that combines shape and linetype... you are actually seeing an overlay of those two legends.  It also means that if you want your color legend to include shape and linetype (like here), you basically have to duplicate those legends (not sure if there's a way to do that), or keep them separate and override the aes of the legend where you want things combined (which is what I do here).

Comment: If you want to define the overriding aes in the legend programmatically, you should be able to define that prior to the `ggplot` call in another data frame and call that within the `guide_legend()` function.